# Auto scroll in javaFX

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, scrollbar

I'm trying to build a Chat Box using javaFX. I'm trying to auto scroll down my page when the current page is filled up. But it doesn't work properly.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChatBox extends Application{
final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
public static void main(String[] args){
launch(args);
}
public void start(Stage stage){
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
textFlow.setPadding(new Insets(10));
textFlow.setLineSpacing(10);
textFlow.setPrefSize(300,300);
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPrefSize(50,30);
Button button = new Button("Send");
button.setPrefSize(80,30);
VBox container = new VBox();
VBox box = new VBox();
box.getChildren().addAll(sp,textFlow);
container.setPadding(new Insets(10));
container.getChildren().addAll(box, new HBox(textField, button));
VBox.setVgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);
VBox.setVgrow(textFlow, Priority.ALWAYS);
textField.prefWidthProperty().bind(container.widthProperty().subtract(button.prefWidthProperty()));

// On Enter press
textField.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        button.fire();
    }
});

button.setOnAction(e -> {
    Text text;
    if(textFlow.getChildren().size()==0){
        text = new Text(textField.getText());
    } else {
        // Add new line if not the first child
        text = new Text("\n" + textField.getText());
    }
    textFlow.getChildren().add(text);
    textField.clear();
    textField.requestFocus();
});
VBox vb = new VBox();
vb.getChildren().addAll(textFlow);
sp.setVmax(440);
sp.setPrefSize(400, 300);
sp.setContent(vb);
sp.vvalueProperty().bind((ObservableValue<? extends Number>) vb.heightProperty());
//sp.setPannable(true);
Scene scene = new Scene(container, 400, 300);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("ChatBox");
stage.show();
}
}
```

When i run it , the page goes down

[image]

here hi goes up though it was the first message and the scroll bar is pointing below though its position should be at the top. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment Pref size for Text Flow because it is causing scroll to  happen as it needs to adjust its size while being inside scroll pane.
Check out as below :

```
package com.grs.stackOverFlow.pack161124;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChatBox extends Application{
    final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage){
        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
        //textFlow.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        textFlow.setLineSpacing(10);
        //textFlow.setPrefSize(300,300);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPrefSize(50,30);
        Button button = new Button("Send");
        button.setPrefSize(80,30);
        VBox container = new VBox();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(sp,textFlow);
        container.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        container.getChildren().addAll(box, new HBox(textField, button));
        VBox.setVgrow(sp, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(textFlow, Priority.ALWAYS);
        textField.prefWidthProperty().bind(container.widthProperty().subtract(button.prefWidthProperty()));

        // On Enter press
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                button.fire();
            }
        });

        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            Text text;
            if(textFlow.getChildren().size()==0){
                text = new Text(textField.getText());
            } else {
                // Add new line if not the first child
                text = new Text("\n" + textField.getText());
            }
            textFlow.getChildren().add(text);
            textField.clear();
            textField.requestFocus();
        });
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(textFlow);
        sp.setVmax(440);
        sp.setPrefSize(400, 300);
        sp.setContent(vb);
        sp.vvalueProperty().bind((ObservableValue<? extends Number>) vb.heightProperty());
        //sp.setPannable(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(container, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ChatBox");
        stage.show();
    }
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: thanks it works now :) but when it scrolls down it should show the current message properly but it shows half of it and i have to scroll down by myself to see it properly. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: @IAmBlake : its again some layout issue, try commenting textFlow.setPadding(new Insets(10)). It worked for me.I have updated answer you can accept if it works for you.If problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `ListView` instead of a `TextFlow` for this. This makes the code a lot simpler, since `ListView` already takes care of line breaks and also provides a `scrollTo` method allowing you to specify a message index to scroll into view:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setPrefSize(50, 30);

    Button button = new Button("Send");
    button.setPrefSize(80, 30);

    VBox container = new VBox();

    ListView<String> listView = new ListView();
    listView.setFocusTraversable(false);
    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

        private final Text text;

        {
            text = new Text();
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(text);

            // bind wrapping width to available size
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
                Insets padding = getPadding();
                return getWidth() - padding.getLeft() - padding.getRight();
            }, widthProperty(), paddingProperty()));

        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                text.setText(null);
            } else {
                text.setText(item);
            }
        }

    });

    container.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    container.getChildren().addAll(listView, new HBox(textField, button));
    VBox.setVgrow(listView, Priority.ALWAYS);

    HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.NEVER);

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
        // add new message
        listView.getItems().add(textField.getText());

        textField.clear();
        textField.requestFocus();

        // scroll to newly added item
        listView.scrollTo(listView.getItems().size()-1);
    };

    textField.setOnAction(handler);
    button.setOnAction(handler);

    Scene scene = new Scene(container, 400, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("ChatBox");
    stage.show();
}
```